# F# Monad how fix datatypes

Tags: f#, monads

I am trying to write a Monad in F# but I can not compile the code and I am getting error FS0001
 error: This expression was expected to have type    'Result'    but here has type    '(Result<'a> -> Result<'b>) -> Result<'b>'

```
open System
type Result<'TSuccess> =
     | Success of 'TSuccess
     | Failure

let bind x f = 
    match x with 
    |  Success x -> f (Success x)
    | Failure -> Failure



let stringToInt (s:string) = 
    try
       let result = s |> int
       Success result 
    with 
       |_-> Failure 

let isPositive (i:int)  = 
    if ( i >  0) then  Success i : Result<int>
    else Failure 

let toString (i:int) = 
    try
       let result = i |> string
       Success result
    with
       |_ -> Failure

let bindIsPositive =  bind isPositive : Result<int>

let bindToString = bind toString : Result<string>

let (>>=) x f = bind f x



let strintToIntIsPositiveIntToString s =  stringToInt >>= bindIsPositive >>= bindToString

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "10"
    let mys = strintToIntIsPositiveIntToString "9"
    Console.WriteLine mys.ToString
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the type of your `bind` is not right:

```
your version : Result<'a> -> (Result<'a> -> Result<'b>) -> Result<'b>
typical type : Result<'a> -> ('a -> Result<'b>) -> Result<'b>
```

It will also be a lot easier to do the rest if you switch the order of parameters to get:

```
bind : ('a -> Result<'b>) -> Result<'a> -> Result<'b>
```

So, you can use the following `bind`:

```
let bind f x = 
    match x with 
    | Success x -> f x
    | Failure -> Failure
```

Once you do this, you can define `bindIsPositive` and `bindToString`. The `bind` operation now takes a function as a first argument, so this works but you have to remove your type annotation:

```
let bindIsPositive =  bind isPositive 
let bindToString = bind toString
```

When composing functions, you can then either use your `>>=` operator, or use normal F# piping and `bind` functions:

```
let strintToIntIsPositiveIntToString x =  x |> stringToInt |> bindIsPositive |> bindToString
let strintToIntIsPositiveIntToString x =  x >>= stringToInt >>= isPositive >>= toString
```